# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (Laravel 8 migration error)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-jetstream

After new laravel8 jetstream with livewire fresh installed
when I run the command php artisan migrate
then it gives the error on my terminal

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lweb and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\liveweb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\liveweb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\liveweb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=lweb", "root", "", [])
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\liveweb>
```

Comment: Check `DB_HOST` entry in your .env file and `config/database.php` for the database you are using, both places the value should be **127.0.0.1** if the database server is also running on the same machine as the webserver

Comment: you havent started apache and mysql yet

Comment: `PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=lweb", "root", "", [])` in the error shows that you have `DB_HOST=mysql` in .env file which can't be resolved to a host address - host means the ip address of the server hosting the database

Answer (score 22):

*Problem solve
just remove DB_HOST=mysql*

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lweb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

*To*

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lweb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: I hope this could be helpful for those who have gone through the solution and not yet succeeded. I had similar problem and tried to change the DB_HOST localhost to 127.0.0.1  also with the name of the container/db host (as mentioned in docker-compose), yet did not help. So I updated my .env file like this: 
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
    DB_PORT=3308 or any other port
    DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
    DB_USERNAME=your_user_name
    DB_PASSWORD=your_password

you could give a try for this in case other option are not working. Hope it helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @vins, your answer helped a lot, I've been searching this for hours.

Comment: @vins You should post your comment as an answer instead. It's helped me with my Laravel Sail project.

Comment: @Shockch4rge thank you for the support :). I would have answered but its not allowed probably the topic has been closed. Well hopefully someone landing here would look into the comments as well like you did and try my suggestion